# change cursor under specific hwnd (window handle)?

Tags: c#, c++, wpf

i wanted to know if it's possible to change the cursor icon only under a specific window handle?

i want the cursor to show loading only while it's pointing on a window (i have its handle), and will return to normal outside of the window.

i'm not under console app / window app / wpf of any kind.

so i tried doing this:

```
IntPtr cursr = LoadCursor(IntPtr.Zero, 32512);
bool retVal = SetSystemCursor(cursr, 32514);
```

but the cursor is changed globally. try...finally will not work, because if i kill the window before the finally block runs, the cursor will stay stuck in loading forever.

any way to change cursor under hwnd then?

i'm working in c#, but c++ is ok aswell, as i'll just do pinvoke.

thx!

Comment: SetSystemCursor() is certainly incorrect.  You are not going to enjoy the correct way much either, you must subclass the window so you can intercept the WM_SETCURSOR message.  Easy to do from within the process, WPF does this and NativeWindow is a simple wrapper class, not easy to do from outside the process.  This requires injecting a DLL into the process, you cannot inject C# code.

Comment: arg.. well, i'm not under WPF or anything. i'm hooking into explorer windows..

Answer (score 0):

### C++ answer:

When you create a window with [`CreateWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632679%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you give it a class name (`lpClassName`). This name should have been previously registered with [`RegisterClass`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633586(v=vs.85).aspx). The `RegisterClass` function takes a [`WNDCLASS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633576(v=vs.85).aspx) parameter, which has a parameter `hCursor`. This is the cursor used when the pointer enters the window. More information on the full process [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648380%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

### C# answer:

Set the [`Cursor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.cursor(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the `System.Windows.FrameworkElement`, for whatever element you wish.

Comment: hi , the window is actually an explorer windows, which i have the hwnd of it (using hooks) - so i'm not creating any window.
is it the still process for already created window?

Comment: No, this doesn't handle the case when the Window is in another process. Messing with Windows Explorer outside any interface it provides is probably a very bad idea, because you'll potentially destabilize it.